# Sorting files into folders

Tags: batch-file

So I have files that include time and date like this "05_14_2014_17_56_01". I want to sort them into folders by date and not time.

So what I was trying to do was get a for loop to make a directory using only the date, and putting the file in there. However the syntax of these batch files is killing me. It should be pretty simple but im having alot of trouble. Can anyone help me out with this.

I tried something like this initially

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\Users\****\Downloads\test
for %%i in (*csv) do (set fileName= %%i & echo !fileName! & mkdir !fileName:~0,10%! & move %%i !fileName:~0,10%!)

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

this not only works, but is even better to read:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in ("*.csv") do ( 
 set "fileName=%%i" 
 echo !fileName! 
 mkdir "!fileName:~0,10%!"
 copy "%%i" "!fileName:~0,10%!"
)
pause
```

I only extracted the `command & command & command` to individual lines.

Ah - and I removed a space, which would make trouble (with your `set`command)

Comment: Hi Thank you for taking the time to answer. For echo it is still spititng out "!fileName!".  For mkDir it is just making a directory with the number 10. And for copy it says system cannot find the file specified. I am using windows 7.

Comment: Ok so sorry an update so I think my other computer was having issues. This code is working for the most part. The issue now is the copy command doesnt work. It keeps telling me bad syntax.

Comment: It works!!!! Thank you so much, god I hate how convoluted the syntax is for batch files. But thank you!